# Difference between remote git repository and current cloned copy

Tags: git, bash, github, git-clone

I am attempting to create a bash script that clones a repository off of a Github account and places it on an NFS volume on a Raspberry Pi cluster. It will be run via cron job at midnight daily. Of course, I don't want to pull from this repo more than I need to. Cloning is done easily enough in the bash script, but how would I check for differences between the current copy of the directory on my machine and the current revision of the repository? I see guides on how to do this with branching and the like, but I don't want to make any changes to the source. I just want to check the differences and re-run `git clone --depth=1 https://github.org/somerepo/something` to the NFS directory if there have been changes.

If I'm misunderstanding how cloning works, please let me know.

Comment: You can use `git fetch --dry-run` to see what, if anything, would be pulled, See a friendly manual near you. `git clone` is used for downloading the repository when you have none.

Comment: Just use `git pull`, it won't download anything if there are no changes.

Comment: `git fetch --all` and then `git branch -av` will indicate when ahead/behind meaning there is a difference.  There is usually no reason to use --dry-run when fetching and there is no way to ask git to compare one thing with another that isn't locally available.   If in doubt perform a local file backup, or copy the entire toplevel directory to another place /tmp/foo/ and test commands there.  `git pull` will modify the working tree if it needs to.  `pull` always does an implicit `fetch` first.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, you want to peek at the remote, but not pull anything down yet?

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

will show the remote heads on origin. You can compare each of these to your remote tracking branches and if the commits differ (or you don't have a remote tracking branch for the remote branch), then fetching would most likely pull in the new commits.

Answer (score 0):

If bare repo is suit you then create local repo with following command: `git clone --mirror`.

For update do `git remote update` in the folder. This command downloads only a difference between local and remote repos.